# GraphDB paths through a a specified node

Tags: path-finding, graphdb

GraphDB 9.9 introduced a feature providing path searches with various configurations. Is there a way to filter obtained paths by a specific node which they need to traverse?

Using the recursive graph pattern instead of the wildcard pattern search does not help - the aim is not to repeatedly look for the specified node, only to pass through it once.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible, but we do have it planned for a future release.

Comment: @EricAya yes, I am, we have the feature in mind but currently there is no planned version for it.